# issue launching application using Red5 1.0.0 RC1 and jdk1.7 on localhost in windows

Tags: windows, localhost, red5

I have installed red51.0.0RC1 on my localhost with jdk1.7 but i am unable to launch applications. I am getting connecting.... /installer/ and while on /demos/port_tester.html, i am again getting connecting... please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try! Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080